# Run batch file normally if the UAC prompt was refused

Tags: batch-file, uac

I wanna make a batch file which prompts for admin rights, but not just that (read until the end before posting pls). Normally i create a vbs script via the batch file which will prompt for admin rights, but the problem is if the user chooses "no" in the UAC window, the batch file won't run, and i want it to run anyway (with or without admin privileges). My code (wrong/incomplete) :

```
@echo off

if "%1" == "S" goto skip

::checks if the user already have admin rights, in this case no prompt needed
net file 1>nul 2>nul
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' goto skip

::create vbs script from which the batch file should run
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > runasAdmin.vbs
echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~0", "S", "", "runas", 1 >> runasAdmin.vbs
start "" runasAdmin.vbs
::here, a code should check if the batch file is running as admin in another process
::if not, goto skip
exit /b

:skip

::commands and stuff...
```

Comment: Use 2 scripts, 1st checks for admin rights and if ok, it runs 2nd script elevated otherwise it runs it non-elevated.

Comment: i want it to prompt for admin rights if it's not elevated, and if the user chooses "no" to the prompt it runs normally, or else elevated

Answer (score 1):

The problem with checking if the process is running as admin is that a non admin will not be able to see the admin process. i.e. admin processes are protected from non elevated eyes. So, that won't work.

ShellExecute returns a HWnd when you code against and this value can be used to check for errors, but of course that doesn't work with the shell.application com object either. So, you can't check the return and do a nice WScript.Quit(err value) for the bat to check.

Using `start "" runasAdmin.vbs` means that your bat file goes straight to the next line, instead of waiting until the UAC prompt has finished. Using `start /wait` or even simpler `cscript -nologo` ensures that the bat waits until the prompt has been answered.

So, you can't check the success/failure of the elevated process creation with VBS nor by checking processes. All that I can think of is to use a temp file creation as a locking mechanism. To make this work, the elevated process needs to create a temp file that the non elevated process checks for, so a small sleep in each is required (achieved with a localhost ping).

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Note: Any user entered parameter will run unelevated
set runningFile=%1
if not defined runningFile goto checkElevation
echo Running as admin > %runningFile%
goto skip

:checkElevation
rem checks if the user already have admin rights, in this case no prompt needed
net file 1>nul 2>nul
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' goto skip

rem create vbs script from which the batch file should run
set filename=%tmp%\RunAsAdmin%random%
set runningFile="%filename%.lck"
set vbscript="%filename%.vbs"
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > %vbscript%
echo UAC.ShellExecute "%0", %runningFile%, "", "runas", 1 >> %vbscript%
cscript -nologo %vbscript%
rem sleep 1 to allow elevated version to create lock file
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 > NUL
del %vbscript%
rem check if running file has been created
if not exist %runningFile% goto skip
if exist %runningFile% del /f %runningFile%
exit /b

:skip
rem sleep 1 so that non elevated version can check lock file created
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 > NUL
echo Running other things here %1

if exist %runningFile% del /f %runningFile%
pause
rem commands and stuff...
```

Answer (score -1):

I optimize this code below:

```
@echo off
@title 
@NET FILE 1>nul 2>nul
@if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (
    @if not defined UAC (
        @set UAC=1;
    ) else (
        @echo. 
        @echo UAC elevating failed !
        @echo.
        @pause
        @exit
    )
    @echo CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^).ShellExecute "%~f0", "%*", "%~dp0", "runas", 1 > %temp%\UACtemp.vbs
    @%temp%\UACtemp.vbs
    @del /f /q %temp%\UACtemp.vbs
    @exit
)
@cd /d %~dp0
@echo on
::command under this line
```

Comment: What's up with all those @ signs? Just the first `@echo off` is sufficient.

Comment: Have you even tested your program before posting it? If you don't know how to program don't play smartass on the Internet.